# Xamarin Android First web request deadly slow

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, xamarin.ios, webclient

the first call I made for my Android Xamarin App is deadly slow, taking up to 10 times the required time.

I already tried all the coding options like "HttpClient", "WebClient" etc

For instance:

```
public string MakeWebRequest(string url)
{
    try
    {
        string responseContent;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);
        request.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy(); // null;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    responseContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return responseContent;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

I tried the same code from Windows Phone App and it works in 1/10 of time. Console app, same result. I tried it also on many device with no success.

All the other requests works well.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Try using `HttpClient` instead of `WebRequest` in combination with the ModernHttpClient message handler (https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient)

Comment: any updates on that topic. still having that issue...